# How Is it possible that usage of API higher than the device's works?

Tags: ios, xcode

There's something not really clear regarding usage of a newer API than the device's version.

Our application's deployment target is 8.0, and we are able to run code that targeting 10.0+ on pre 10.0 devices without crashing.

Take a look for example on `greatestfinitemagnitude`:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgfloat/1845207-greatestfinitemagnitude

The target is 10.0+. However, we've tested it successfully on an 8.1 and 8.4 devices, without crashing

How is it possible?

Furthermore, how can we really make sure we are not using an api that is not supported.
Can we make xCode show errors and not compile if we're using unsupported API?

Comment: Xcode will warn you if you are using API that is not supported for the selected target OS.

Comment: `greatestFiniteMagnitude` is not an API, it's a static variable defined in the SDK, so the important point here is not the deployment target or the version of iOS you run on, but the version of the SDK you compile and link with.